# <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1c0c7ae0> { URL: (null) } in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

getting issue with the following code

```
-(void)AddEmpService:(NSDictionary *)params
{

    recordResults = FALSE;
    OutPutStringName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [OutPutStringName appendString: @"string"];

    NSString *urlstr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.seen.com/SeenApi/Service.svc/EmpService?type=Insert&Id=&ClassId=%@&Name=%@&Desg=%@&Age=%@&Add=%@&Sal=%@&Gend=%@&Phone=%@&EmpId=%@",[params objectForKey:@"Id"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpName"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpDesignation"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpAge"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpAddress"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpSalary"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpGender"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpPhone"],[params objectForKey:@"EmpId"]];

    NSLog(@"dict is %@",params);
    urlstr=[urlstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlstr);
    NSURL *url=    [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"the request %@",theRequest);
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

}
```

NSLog(@"%@",urlstr); is

```
http://www.seen.com/SeenApi/Service.svc/EmpService?type=Insert&Id=&ClassId=63&Name=Mark&Desg=Teacher&Age=25&Add=New%%20York&Sal=5000&Gend=Male&Phone=0987654321&EmpId=235
```

But getting the null for
NSLog(@"the request %@",theRequest);

```
the request <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1c0c7ae0> { URL: (null) }
2017-11-21 14:07:36.262 Emp[7070:2394869] ERROR with theConenction
```

Please help me to figure out the issue.TIA

Comment: There are two consecutive `%` characters in the string. It's highly recommended to use `NSURLComponents` and `NSURLQueryItem` to compose the URL. It handles the percent encoding implicitly.

Comment: could you please correct the string @vadian

Comment: I can’t because I don’t know the exact contents of the dictionary. But instead of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` better use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` to add the proper percent encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlstr stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]]];
```